# What is a basis for the space of anti-symmetric $3\times 3$ matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I tried to find a basis for the subspace of 3-by-3 anti-symmetric matrices - but for nothing.

How to find such a basis?

Comment: I take it you mean the basis of the vector space of all antisymmetric $3 \times 3$ matrices? (A matrix doesn't have a basis.)

Comment: @CliveNewstead of-course it doesn’t that’s why I mentioned the fact the I need to find the sub-space of the Matrix...

Comment: A matrix doesn't have subspaces either!

Comment: I've edited your question. If it doesn't reflect what you mean precisely, please feel free to roll back.

Comment: In addition to being a subspace, it is also a Lie algebra denoted by $so(3, \mathbb{R})$.

Comment: You will probably get more help from people if you improve on your "accept" rate. And FYI, it is always good form to upvote any and all answers that you benefited from as way of saying, "Thank you" to those who took the time to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint 1:** What value must the diagonal entries take? And if the value of the $(i,j)^{\text{th}}$ entry is $a$, what is the value of the $(j,i)^{\text{th}}$ entry?

**Hint 2:** Hover over the grey box below when you've thought a bit about Hint 1.

> The bottom-left entries are determined by the upper-right entries, over which you have free choice.

Comment: Maybe I kinda forgot to mention, "Find the Basis and the dimension of an Anti Symmetric sub-Space arrangement 3x3"

Comment: @user1798362: I don't understand what you mean. I presume you're trying to find a basis for the subspace (of the $9$-dimensional vector space of all $3 \times 3$ matrices) consisting of the antisymmetric matrices.

Comment: Ok $-$ well that's what my hints are working towards. If you need another hint, let me know!