# How do I find a basis for the $kerT$ of the linear transformation $T(A) = A+A^t$ defined as $T: R^{2\times 2} \rightarrow R^{2\times 2}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I find a basis for the $kerT$ of the linear transformation $T(A) = A+A^t$?
I don't have any clue of how to start this question, hope someone can help me here :)

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/272065/what-is-a-basis-for-the-space-of-anti-symmetric-3-times-3-matrices.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Use the definition: $A \in \ker T \iff T(A)=0 \iff A+A^t = 0$.

How many degrees of freedom for the entries of $A$ are left? What are they?

Solution:

> $A \in \ker T$ iff $A$ is anti-symmetric. So, it's diagonal is $0$ and the part below the diagonal is determined by the part above the diagonal, which can be arbitrary. A basis for $\ker T$ is thus the set of matrices of the form $E-E^t$, where $E$ is an upper triangular [elementary matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix).

Comment: I tried, but in what way should I use it?

Comment: What is degrees of freedom?